Laggy video on ubuntu installed on the old mac mini
I have a mac mini mid 2011 with following specs:

Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 МБ Intel 6th Generation (Sandy Bridge)
Intel Core i5 2.3x4

It is connected to a TV with hdmi cable
When it had macos installed, everything was fine with playing videos on it. Both online streaming videos (youtube, etc.) and local mkv's
Then I decided to install ubuntu (22.04.5 LTS) and now when I play videos - it's almost impossible to watch. There are visible microfreezes every few seconds. Watch dynamic scenes turns into a slideshow.
And it happens everywhere - online, local.
Is there anything I can do with that? installing better video drivers?
I gotta say this machine runs several docker containers (I'm using it as a server) but it also did the same when macos was installed.
My previous experience with ubuntu was running simple remote servers on VPS, using it only through terminal. Now I wanted to turn an old macmini into both the local server (NAS, plex, etc.) and the media player connected directly to the TV. And it's the first time I'm dealing with drivers and overall GUI on ubuntu.
I switched from macos to ubuntu because macos wasn't able to stream netflix (lack of support for the hardware) and because I thought I would benefit more from using this hardware with linux system rather than macos.
